# How should I define a set number of bits in a typedef?

Tags: c++, struct, typedef

### The Problem

I'm currently trying to simulate some firmware in C++11. In the firmware we have a fixed data length of 32 bits, we split this 32 bits into smaller packets e.g we have a packet which as a size of 9 bits, another of 6 which gets packed into the 32 bit word.

In C++ I want to ensure the data I type in is of those lengths. I don't care if I overflow, just that only the 9 bits are operated on or passed onto another function.

Ideally I'd like some simple typedef like:

```
only_18_bits some_value;
```

### My Attempt

```
struct sel_vals{
int_fast32_t m_val : 18;
int_fast8_t c_val : 5;
}
```

But this is a little annoying as I'd have to do this whenever I want to use it:

```
sel_vals somevals;
somevals.m_val = 5;
```

Seems a little verbose to me plus I have to declare the struct first.

Also for obvious reasons, I can't just do something like:

```
typedef sel_vals.m_val sel_vals_m_t;
typedef std::vector<sel_vals_m_t>;
```

I could use `std::bitset<9>` but whenever I want to do some maths I have to convert it to unsigned, it just gets a little messy. I want to avoid mess.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am not sure what you would have to do different if your type was a simple integer. You still have to do `int somevals; somevals = 5;` So how is it you *want* to use this that using *bitfields* doesn't allow?

Comment: Is there a reason not to create a tiny class with a mask value it applies to whatever value it's constructed from or assigned?  You can have an `operator int() const` for convenient use.

Comment: @Galik Because I have a lot of simulated data input from text files into this program. Sometimes we may want to change these "packet" lengths inside the 32 bit word to optimise what we're doing. You can imagine that actually the above is `m_val : SIZE_M` where `SIZE_M` is a constant of `size_t` defined elsewhere. It's a safety precaution to ensure that the same data I input here gives the same result as when I input the data into the firmware.

Comment: @TonyD That's a good idea, or even a template could work better. I'm just bouncing ideas around at the moment before I commit to a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a wrapper facade, something along these lines:

```
#include <cstdint>

template<int nbits> class bits {

   uint64_t value;

   static const uint64_t mask = (~(uint64_t)0) >> (64-nbits);

public:
   bits(uint64_t initValue=0) : value(initValue & mask) {}

   bits &operator=(uint64_t newValue)
   {
       value=newValue & mask;
   }

   operator uint64_t() const { return value; }
};

//

bits<19> only_19_bits_of_precision;
```

With a little bit of work, you can define math operator overloads that directly operate on these templates.

With a little bit of more work, you could work this template to pick a smaller internal value, `uint32_t`, `uint16_t`, or `uint8_t`, if the `nbits` template parameter is small enough.